# Where() performance issues with a high number of returned rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server database table that have about 3 million records in it. I have an MVC site with a page to display data from this table, and I'm running into extensive performance issues.

Running a simple query like this takes about 25-30 seconds to return about two thousand rows:

```
_dbContext.Contracts
    .Where(c => c.VendorID == vendorId)
    .ToList();
```

I thought maybe the sql being produced was doing something weird, but it's pretty simple:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ContractID] AS [ContractID], 
    [Extent1].[VendorID] AS [VendorID], 
    [Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
FROM [dbo].[Contracts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[VendorID] = @p__linq__0
```

But the difference is that when I run this query directly on the database, it only takes 3-5 seconds. So I feel like EF might be doing something strange.

Is there any way I can improve the performance of this? Either on the SQL side or in my solution with EF?

The site is a bit old, it's MVC 3 with EF 4

Comment: Is this a new DbContext instance?  If you have long-lived DbContext instances, the change tracker will accumulate lots of object instances, which can slow down object materialization.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it's a new instance

Comment: How did you configure the Lazy Loading? Maybe EF is trying to bring in the related objects as well.

Answer (score 2):

On the SQL side you should create a non-clustered index on VendorID column of the Contracts table.

Comment: So the missing index does not affect when the query is run without linq?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - The index is important in both cases.  The difference may be in caching of the data.  Run each timing test twice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like code-side issue (Not SQL-side issue).
Have you added something to the 'Contracts' class constructor?